# iPhone : Sharepoint GetListItemChangesSinceToken method returns item recursively

Tags: iphone, ios, sharepoint

I'm integrating sharepoint web services with my iPhone app. Done with `GetListCollection` and `GetListItems` services integration. While trying with `GetListItemChangesSinceToken` service for sync purpose instead of using `GetListItems` service, I'm getting all the items of the document library in the response which means it pulls out all the items recursively from that doc library, whereas I need only the items specific to that library (not the subfolder items)

This is my Folder Hierarchy

Testing -> Testing 1(SF), Testing doc1(D), Testing doc2(D) -> Testing 2(SF), Testing1 doc1(D)

SF - SubFolder;
D - Document

The Soap message I'm using is :

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
                         <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
                         instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
                         xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
                         <soap:Body>
                         <GetListItemChangesSinceToken 
                         xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">
                         <listName>%@</listName>
                         <queryOptions><QueryOptions>
                         <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
                         <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
                         <Folder>%@</Folder></QueryOptions>
                         </queryOptions>
                         </GetListItemChangesSinceToken>
                         </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",listName,pathRef];
```

The parameters which I'm passing to get the items of first level folder (Testing) are
`listName`: Testing
`pathRef`: Testing

This request returns all the items in the Testing folder(Testing 1(SF), Testing doc1(D), Testing doc2(D), Testing 2(SF), Testing1 doc1(D)) whereas I need only the items specific to that folder (Testing 1(SF), Testing doc1(D), Testing doc2(D)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the MSDN article on this [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitemchangessincetoken(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitemchangessincetoken%28v=office.12%29.aspx), specifically the section on queryOptions and the Folder part.

You'll just want to add a folder option for the Root Folder, this is a server relative path according to this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2008/01/21/synchronizing-with-windows-sharepoint-services-part-1.aspx

So try

```
<folder>site/list/</folder>
```